# Access commit webhook message in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, github

I've got a Jenkins server integrated with a GitHub Organization through a GitHub App and the Jenkins GitHub Branch Source plugin, and it is working fine and triggering builds on commits as intended.

However, I would like to, in my pipeline, know who triggered this build. As far as Jenkins is concerned, it's a branch event, but the webhook message sent from github contains information about the pushing user which I would like to know for further actions like notifications.

Can I retrieve this information somehow?